# SharePoint and WCF for anonymous user in load balancing servers

Tags: sharepoint

I am having a WCF web service and i am uploading a document to SharePoint site through this service.In my staging server it works fine with a single server but in the production we are having four servers in Load balancing and it is giving me the error...

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://jai-dms-app.rajdiscoms.com:1111/_vti_bin/Discom/Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Please help me ..

Comment: Please look in the server logs and let us know more details.

Comment: Which server logs i need to look whether SharePoint logs or windows logs can you just tell me where i need to check...

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are having an issue is most likely due to the loop back check. You will need to update the registry to fix that
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926642/en-us
You may also want to ensure your load balance has sticky sessions

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the thing is Previously the service is running fine and once the service account gets changed(SqlSerive account) its is not working and giving me this error.